# Understanding of the part of the code

Tags: scheme, sicp

Please, can you explain to me what the part of if (the one that is noted with ***) is doing? The explanation given was that it adds conditional to the (term a). However, I think in that case there must be written something like:

```
 (if (filter term a)
```

The whole code is below:

```
 (define (filtered-accumulate combiner null-value term a next b filter) 
    (if (> a b) 
   null-value 
   (combiner (***if (filter a) 
                 (term a) 
                 null-value)*** 
             (filtered-accumulate combiner null-value term (next a) next b filter))))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's `if` and it pretty much work the same way as `if` in other languages except that it **always** evaluates to a value. So `(filter a)` is evaluated and if it is a true value (thus anything other than `#f`) the result of the `if` is the result of `(term a)`. Otherwise the evaluation of the variable `null-value` will be the result. Since this is the expression in argument position of the form `(combiner ...)` that value will become the first argument in that form.

Both `combiner` and `filter` are just variables the evaluate to whatever they were passed and from the code to work they must be functions, but their names do not dictate how they are used. I have no idea if `filter` takes one or two arguments. It might be that the name indicates that this is a filter predicate and then it should only take one argument. Again, educated guess only and I might be wrong.